# Tomcat/IIS isapi_redirect connectors not working

Tags: java, tomcat, iis, isapi, isapi-redirect

Versions/OS

- Tomcat 6
- IIS 10
- Java jdk1.6.0_23
- Windows 10 Server

I've been trying to connect a Tomcat served web application to IIS following the applications step by step instruction for getting Tomcat and the IIS connectors working.

Tomcat is able to serve the site and I can connect to it through Tomcats port *http://localhost:8080/sitename*. Upon navigating to the IIS hosted site (on port 80 as defaulted), I see the normal default IIS site screen for IIS 10. If I were to access the site directory *http://localhost/sitename*, it brings me to a 404 page.

If it helps, here is the detailed error information:

```
Detailed Error Information:

Module
   IIS Web Core 

Notification
   MapRequestHandler 

Handler
   StaticFile 

Error Code
   0x80070002 

Requested URL
   http://localhost:80/unanet/ 

Physical Path
   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\unanet\ 

Logon Method
   Anonymous 

Logon User
   Anonymous
```

My guess is the IIS site is having trouble using the `isapi_redirect.dll` file to establish a connection. The goal of this is to use IIS to add NTLM authentication for our users, so we utilize the IIS connectors for us.

I have all the necessary property files/configurations. I've checked the java environment variables. I've verified read/write rights for the users in the system, I'm running out of things to consider.

Comment: "following the applications step by step instruction", then whoever writes that up is the one you should chase. `isapi_redirect.dll` is known to have many issues like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the following code to web.config：

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" >
    <remove name="UrlRoutingModule"/>    
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```